# How to convert component to Image in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

We know using file reference save method we can save the component as image in flex 3, but i am using flex 3.0 version, i did not get the save method in file reference class. Its available on flex 3.4.0 onwards.Do we have any other option to make the component to image in flex 3.0 compiler using flex builder IDE?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If this case allows to use HTML5, it could be possible.

```
    public function capturePage(): void
    {
        var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(this.width, this.height);
        bmp.draw(this, new Matrix());

        // convert to JPEG.
        var fileData:ByteArray = new JPEGEncoder().encode(bmp);

        var base64: Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
        base64.encodeBytes(fileData);

        ExternalInterface.call("saveAsImage", "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+base64.toString());
    }
```

index.template.html

```
<title>${title}</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function saveAsImage(value)
{
    // open new window. You will be able to save as image.
    window.open(value);

    // or use HTML5 FileWriter API here.
}
</script>
<script src="AC_OETags.js" language="javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information,it works fine for me, i will try with filewriter to save as image format on local system or server.

Answer (score 0):

```
        private function doSave():void 
        {              
             var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(canvas.width,canvas.height);
            bmp.draw(canvas,new Matrix());

            var filedate:ByteArray = new JPEGEncoder().encode(bmp);

            var uploadURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
            uploadURL.url = parentApplication.ServerUrl+"...../imageupload.php?fileName="+yourfilename;
            uploadURL.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
            uploadURL.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            uploadURL.data = filedate;
            var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);                
            urlLoader.load(uploadURL);
        }
```

PHP File : imageupload.php

```
    <?php
      $fileName = $_REQUEST['fileName'] . ".jpeg";
      $fp = fopen( "../tempfolder/".$fileName, 'wb' );
      fwrite( $fp, $GLOBALS[ 'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA' ] );
      fclose( $fp );
     ?>
```